# How would it be possible to have a Windows Phone 8 application interact directly with a Windows PC ? (Using WP8 as an input device for Windows 8)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a Windows Phone 8 application that can send mouse movements from the phone to a Windows 8/7 PC. Can't find a good place to start with this being that there's no documentation of this even being possible other than the few RDP Client apps in the App Sore (which I can't find how).

How would it be possible to have a Windows Phone 8 application interact directly with a Windows PC ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. At the end of the day you're trying to communicate with windows from another computer. A keyboard and mouse are simple devices with simple drivers. For computer to computer communications you have to establish some form of connectivity first.

For example if you wanted to be a keyboard then that keyboard's driver would been to installed. How the driver and app communicate is down to you of course.

The simplest way I would have thought is to have a service on the PC that listens to your device's communications and then control the PC on your behalf. Lucky for you there is a service already built into windows to do this. It's called [Windows Remote Desktop Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee236407.aspx). All you have to do is talk RDP to it.

There are some open source RDP clients available. If I was doing this project I would start with those and determine what I'd need to do. Also you will probably find that the Windows Phone 8 os has RDP client APIs available so something like [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) and it's Windows API layer  abstraction [WINPR](http://www.freerdp.com/2012/05/24/winpr-windows-portable-runtime/) might just be what you need to examine first.

Good luck.